# Maven project execute without ide

Tags: maven, selenium, jar, pom.xml

**I do a selenium test using Maven. I have more than 20 test classes. How do I export and run them without ide ?
I am also using the POM structure.**

Comment: **'How do I export and run them without ide'** - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Typically these tests would be run as part of the integration test phase using the [failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) and then run maven up to the [verify](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) phase (such as running `mvn verify`).  What have you tried so far?

Comment: try mvn clean test command to execute your project without IDE

Comment: I searched spring boot and plugin and , jenkins. But I dont understand these term.

Comment: It needs to work on a non-ide computer. Like jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open terminal/cmd, navigate to you project directory and use maven command:

```
mvn clean test
```

- clean — delete target directory
- test — run tests

If you want to specify which exactly class you want to run (no all like above) you can run a -Dtest parameter like suggested:

```
mvn clean -Dtest=testClass install
```

Comment: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? I get an error . Do I need to download jdk

Comment: You said that you are using maven. If so, above commands are enough to run tests. Maven must be installed on the machine and added to environment variables. You can check this in cmd: mvn --version.

Answer (score 0):

First navigate to folder where your project's pom.xml is located.

```
cd DirectoryWherePOMisLocated
```

then execute below command,

```
mvn clean -Dtest=classNameWhichYouWantToExecute install
```

If you want to execute multiple classes just separate them with , in -Dtest argument.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If you want to execute multiple classes just separate them with , in -Dtest argument.  What is the mean ? Can you explain please?  I am new in automation test

Comment: As you mentioned you have multiple classes in your framework.  Given that you want to execute selective classes (not all classes) then use, mvn clean -Dtest=class1,class2,class3 install

Comment: thank you but No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? I get an error . What can I do ?

Comment: first step would be to check java version, run java --version on command prompt. If you are getting JRE version instead of JDK then your PATH variable in pointing to JRE instead of JDK. Update you PATH variable to point to jdk (example: C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0.221\bin)

Comment: one more question. How do I get test reports without ide ?

Comment: you can use maven surefire plug in for reporting purpose. refer https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html